# Rsync include from and exclude from a list

Tags: bash, rsync

I am trying to use rsync include-from and exclude-from commands to ignore or only copy listed files/directories from a source. The list is in a text file. For some reason the command does not execute. Why is this the case?

Code:

```
rsync -ar —exclude-from 'exclude-list.txt' source/* destination/

rsync -ar —include-from 'exclude-list.txt' source2/* destination/
```

In exclude-list.txt:

```
file1
file2
/dir1
/dir2
```

Comment: cross-posting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/433544/93768

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the wrong syntax. your command would rather be

```
rsync -ar --exclude-from='exclude-list.txt' source/ destination/
```

the exclude-part was completely wrong, but also the source isn't properly specified. first you don't need a `*` and then be careful with using closing `/` or not. - it means different things!

i would strongly advise you to read the [man-page](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html) (at least the parts you need) and first run your command with `-n` or `--dry-run` to see what would happen, but without really changing anything. probably `-v`, `--stats` and `--progress` (or even `--info=FLAGS`) would be interesting for this case.